# systemAdminMenuBlockPage callback not respecting menu link permissions

Tags: 8, commerce, navigation

I added a custom permission on "admin/commerce/config" to disable access for certain user roles.

```
class RouteSubscriber extends RouteSubscriberBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
    $events[RoutingEvents::ALTER] = 'onAlterRoutes';
    return $events;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  protected function alterRoutes(RouteCollection $collection) {
      if ($route = $collection->get('commerce.configuration')) {
        $route->setRequirements(['_permission' => 'administer commerce configuration']);
      }
  }
}
```

The page can now only be accessed when user has the permissions 'administer commerce configuration'. But it is still visible on the "admin/commerce" page.
The page url's are build by the systemAdminMenuBlockPage callback. The function getAdminBlock (core/modules/system/src/SystemManager.php) builds the menu and has a $element->access->isAllowed function,but this keep returning 1. And so its still printed on the overview page.

Any suggestions for fixing this issue?